# Is it possible to have screen displaying with exactly only CPU

Tags: graphics-card, display, cpu

I did search, but it seems like general computer CPU would have no video signal output to monitor (when no display adapter in between? here doesn't mean the processing unit).

I'm really curious about it, as they say CPU would be overburden when GPU/Integrated Graphic Chip is not power enough. From here I think CPU of course have the Instruction Set that can be used for graphic processing, but why, with only CPU, there is still no display on screen.

Im actually also looking at how a cycle of displaying single frame on screen being done by the computer nowadays. But the main question is, is it possible to display with only CPU.

Comment: If this is entirely possible depends on if the CPU has a iGPU and if the motherboard supports a video output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot output to a *physical* display without some kind of GPU. The GPU includes the hardware necessary to scan through the display frame buffers and output a signal that a monitor can understand.

If you do not need a physical display though, a GPU is not technically needed. The CPU is *capable* of drawing a window and doing the desktop composition necessary. Technically speaking this is what is going on when you run a virtual machine (or qemu emulated machine) and do not enable any hardware video acceleration.

You can still connect to that virtual machine via a remote desktop app and see a display.